# How to center my entire web application using div tag?

Tags: css

My JSF web application is left aligned and it looks odd. I wanted to make its appearance centered in all browsers.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
#main {
margin:0 auto; 
text-align:center; 
}
```

I also tried:

`div align="center"...`

inside html body, but no use.

How can I center `#main`?

Comment: i use the same margin:0 auto; u can experiment with the help of firebug

Comment: #main needs a fixed widths for this to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
#main{
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Also remember to set a width else it will be 100% causing it to be the whole page making it look left aligned.

Comment: +1 best answer. Also explaining why it looks like left-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

```
#main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px; /* or whatever you like */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`#main` needs a fixed width for this to work: http://jsfiddle.net/RVpUQ/1/

```
#main {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 55px;
}
```

Comment: What this `background` has to do with centering the webpage?

Comment: nothing. copied it from my example on jsfiddle where it's used to show that the box is actually centered. thanks. i'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a width and to set the margin to auto

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add a width** as well.

```
#main {
  margin:0 auto; 
  width: 75%;
  text-align:center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <body>
    <div class="divContainer">
        <div class="divCentral">
            <h1>My content herer</h1>
        </div>
     </div>        

 </body>
</html>
```

and CSS is

```
.divContainer
{
  background-color:gray;
  width:100%;
  min-height:500px;
}
.divCentral
{
 width:90%;
 background-color:white;
 min-height:480px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/eptGU/4/

Comment: What this `min-height` is used here for? IE does not support it and it has nothing to do with the question. (Nearly the same for `background-color`.)

Comment: Fatal : Min-height and background-color gave to show the central div different from the container div. Just for visual understanding. The min-height and background color has nothing to do with the question. I added it for the demo.

Comment: Ok, a demo is nice. But you posted 22 lines of code for something can be done with 4 lines well-formatted code. The important things may get lost under so much boilerplate-demo-code. But it's your style not mine ...

Comment: you shouldn't use min-height as a general rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css setting it like this :

this goes on the div style:

**border: 1px solid white; height: 90%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; top: 0px; position: relative; width: 879px;**

so you define a width for the div and then browser autocenters it.

and you must set the following attribute into the body style:

**text-align:center;**

this goes on the style of the body tag of the page this makes iexplorer implements the correct behavior.